# Sansevieria disease

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

Anyone know what is happening to this sansevieria?
[image: sansevieria with disease]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sun damage as if the plant was moved from shade to sunny place.

Was it exposed to direct sunlight recently?